# Generate documentation for node module depdencies

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a documentation (HTML, txt, whatever) of a node module from its `package.json`.

Let' suppose this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ov-aib-phone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Utility for handling phone numbers stored in CIF database",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitstash.aib.pri/scm/ovc/ov-aib-phone.git"
  },
  "author": "OneView Team",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aib-build-utils": "1.0.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "1.0.5",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-html2js": "0.2.2",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-messages": "1.5.9"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ]
}
```

I would like simply a plugin which generates me a doc related to the module (not the code inside it!) but just the name, repo URL and dependencies for example.

I know I could write it because I have just to parse a JSON and generate a file (HTML would be much better), but I was wondering if the wheel has been already invented for it.

Thanks a lot